# Calculating gradient in 2D

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Could anyone find the below gradient 2D? $a$ and $r_0$ are constants.
$$\nabla  \frac{\exp\left(-(\vert r-r_0\vert-a)\right)}{\vert r-r_0\vert}$$

Comment: Are $r$ and $r_0$ vectors?

Comment: No solution is a vector, so r is sqrt(x^2+y^2) @rrogerr

Comment: Is this something related to Yukawa's potential? In that case $r_0$ and $r$ not being vectors doesn't make sense...

Comment: No, I'm sure that R IS  sqrt(x^2+y^2)

Comment: Last question, Is there a remote possibility that $r = x\hat x + y \hat y$ and $r_0 = x_0\hat x + y_0 \hat y$ and $\lVert r- r_0 \rVert = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2}$?

Comment: It is correct, but as you mentioned the size of distance have been entered the equation@rrogerr

Comment: Do you know how to solve it in this case?@rrogerr

Comment: Though I answered below, I think you should add more details to your question (definitions of $r$, $r_0$...), your attempt to solve it or what you find specially troublesome about that problem. That's how MSE works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yukawa's potential, huh?

Take $\vec R = r - r_0 = x\hat x + y\hat y$ and $R = \lVert r - r_0\rVert$. Oserve that solving the problem in terms of $\vec R$ will give you the solution in the coordinate system in which $r_0 = \vec 0$. Applying the rule of the derivative of the product:

$$
\nabla \frac{e^{-R-a}}{R} = e^{-a} \nabla \frac{e^{-R}}{R} = e^{-a} [e^{-R}\nabla \frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{R}\nabla e^{-R}]\qquad(1)
$$

An useful rule for finding the gradient of functions that only depend on the distance $R$ to the origin:

$$
\nabla f(R) = f'(R) \hat R \qquad(2)
$$

where

$$\hat R = \frac{\vec R}{R} = \frac{x\hat x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{y\hat y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

You can use that rule to solve $\nabla e^{-R}$:

$$
\nabla e^{-R} = -e^{-R} \hat R = -e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \left( \frac{ x\hat x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{y\hat y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right) \qquad(3)
$$

Well, it's up to you to calculate $\nabla r^{-1}$ using (2). After that insert both my result (3) and yours in (1) and don't forget to substitute $\vec R = r- r_0$

Comment: Does relation 2 works in 2D?

Comment: My result is -\hat{R}/ R^2. Is it correct?

Comment: Your result is ok and the rule works in 2D